# Is there any way to search image by image in Mac finder?

Tags: finder

Mac version is OS X EI Capitan
What I want is just the same like google image Search by image service but the search region is a specific folder of my Mac disk.

Comment: No, nothing like this is currently available in OS X (at least nothing part of the OS).    There may be some third party apps that do this...  but I'm not aware of any.

Comment: Would [PhotoSweeper](http://overmacs.com) be something appropriate?

Comment: Issue with PhotoSweeper is you need to first add the images in and then run a comparison. That's probably not going to be easy to add all your images on all your drives. May not even cope?

Answer (score 1):

Seems this similar image detector could let you do like this, it stated " Add a photo to compare against the photos in chosen folders and find duplicate and similar ones from the folders "
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/similar-image-detector/id892627565?mt=12